# UTF from included file - PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I am including my lang from separate file. As it's translate I need it to be code in UTF8, how ever i try it display D�tum vytvorenia pr�padu  instead of Datum vytvoření případu

It looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$lang = array();

//All
$lang['YES'] = 'Áno';
$lang['NO'] = 'Nie';
$lang['NOT_AVALIABLE'] = 'Nie je k dispozícii';
$lang['CURRENCY'] = 'Mena';
.........
```

After that i just call it in class like:

```
  public function fetchByVinAxnmrss($con) {
     $success = false;
    include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file; 
     try{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_cases WHERE vin = :vin ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 60";
            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                 echo  "<dt>".$lang['AXNMRS_CASE_CREATED_DATE']."</dt>";
```

What i try:

- Class UTF8 is correct becuase it's working there if i just write
  directly the words without including lang text
- All Files are saved with UTF-8 coding
- Try to use Meta adn PHP for set UTF8 chars

I don't really know what else i can try.

Comment: there has to be some part of your process that's not in UTF-8. and could you maybe provide more of your code? I don't see a single `echo` - and it's also not clear to me how the language file looks and how **exactly** you are including it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **htmlentities** function before display string.

```
$encodedString  = htmlentities($badString,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_XML1 | ENT_XHTML | ENT_HTML5, "ISO-8859-1");
```

For european words you need to encode string with **ISO-8859-1** for othre languge characters you can refer 
Supported charsets table on this php reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'ENT_SUBSTITUTE' in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 1420 Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_DISALLOWED - assumed 'ENT_DISALLOWED' in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 1420 Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML401 - assumed 'ENT_HTML401' in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 1420 Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_XML1 - assumed 'ENT_XML1' in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 1420 Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_XHTML - assumed 'ENT_XHTML' in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 1420

Comment: This mighe be versioning issue, As per above reference link documentation in **Changelog** part you we can see this constants were added in php 5.4.0 version. You can omit this parameter which are creating issues and try it. May be that can help us.